# Markdown "plugin" for Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, markdown

There is a plugin called [Markdown Mode](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0855e23e-4c4c-4c82-8b39-24ab5c5a7f79) for Visual studio 2010, that enables you to preview Markdown in Visual studio 2010 (duh). Is there something similar for Visual studio ***2008***?

What would be the easiest way to enable Markdown preview in VS2008?